# Quad-Channel on ASUS M4A88TD-M motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard, dual-channel

I'm learning about RAM multi-channel and I have doubts:

1. Is possible a quad-channel(8GB: 4x2GB) with M4A88TD-M?
2. What is better: A quad-channel(4x2GB) or a dual-channel(2x4GB)?

Thank's in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to use dual, triple, quad or any other [multi-channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture) access is not solely determined by the motherboard. Usually it is the memory controller which is determines this.

Motherboards can still offer less than the memory controller is able to, but that is rare.

Also note that the memory controller on older motherboards was in the [northbridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_%28computing%29), but these days it is usually integrated on the CPU.

If we look up the [M4A88TD-M](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A88TDM/) then you can see that it is a motherboard for an AMD Phenon/Athlon/Sempron CPU and that means it is limited to the very common dual channel mode.

Note that triple- or quad-channel do not mean that you get a faster setup. It allows for more memory bandwidth but the CPU must be able to use that. E.g. take the classic Intel core i7 [920](http://ark.intel.com/products/37147/Intel-Core-i7-920-Processor-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI) (quad core, 8 treads) with came with triple channel support but not not gain much from using the third channel. (The design was sound though because later hexa core CPU's got released for the same socket-1366 and those could use the extra bandwidth).

Moving to your second question:
Assuming the same setup then quad channel is better than dual channel. However quad-channel is not an option for your setup. Like 95% of all consumer boards at this time you get the option of using one DIMM in single channel mode. Two DIMMs in dual-channel, or four DIMMs, both in dual channel mode.

Comment: Thanks! I understood perfectly, but in my case so, a 4x2gb(2 dual-channels, each with 4gb) is better than an single dual-channel(2x4gb)?

Comment: No, it is equal. A memory access will use either memory pair. Which makes 2x4GB better because it allows room for future expansion while providing the same speed.

Comment: Is that I have 4GB in dual channel(2x2GB), so wonder if it's a good deal to buy more 2x2GB.

Comment: More than 4GB RAM is a good thing, even on not-heavy used desktops. Depending on your budget and needs that can be an addition 2x2GB or more (e.g. additions 2x4GB, 2x8GB, ... or even a single additional DIMM. A single DIMM would not allow dual channel access but generally more memory beats faster memory).

Comment: Ok! So I will purchase more 2x4GB. It is thought that a dual-channel 2x4GB would not work with a second dual-channel 2x2GB.